# Hi, I am getting error between pages. Can you suggest a solution for my page?

Tags: flutter

When switching pages

--- new GestureDetector (
                 onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed (context, "/ lanc"), ---

My lanc page doesn't open. I'll be very happy if you suggest a solution. Thank you

---

main.dart --mypage-- 
=>

import 'arayuz/lanc.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => ScaffoldOge(),

```
    "/hello": (context) => Hello(),

    "/lanc": (context) => Kalp(),
  },
),
```

);
}

---

--My Error-- 
=>
Another exception was thrown: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/lanc", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code isn't clear enough for me to spot the error , but i can suggest you to watch these tutorials it'll be very helpful,this [by_reso_coder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyvwx7o277U&t=43s) and this one [by_filledStacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlArCl8jvlo)

Comment: I will watch. main problem "Couldn't find a generator for route RouteSettings (" / lanc ", null) in the _WidgetsAppState."